# How to create equals methods for multiple classes which are dependent upon each other

Tags: java, equals

I seem to have run into a bit of a snag. I have 3 classes which need overridden equals methods. However, as I currently understand their class structure, this is not possible. I'm looking for some guidance on the matter.

I have class A, inside of which is class B. Class A "has-a" class B.

I have class B, inside of which is class C. Class B "has-a" class C.

I have class C, inside of which is class A. Class C "has-a" class A.

How does one correctly define an equals method, when seemingly each equals method is dependent upon another? Should I restructure the class relationships, or can I define an equals method given this relation?

Thanks!

EDIT: To further clarify, here's some more info on the classes (this isn't what they actually are, but a better understanding of why this relationship is so):

Class A is a box.
Class B is a smaller box.
Class C is an object.

Each A has a B.
Each B has several Cs.
Each C needs to know not only its B, but its A; therefore it takes as a field an A, giving us this circular relationship.

Comment: So you have cyclic references? MEMORY LEAK ALERT!

Comment: why....? you are forcing car intances to be equal to Person instances think that you will need to make it reflexive, symmetric,transitive, consistent...

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ too many english words I dont understand XD

Comment: Explain memory leak alert? @Antoniossss

Comment: If A holds B that holds C that holds A it is possible that those 3 objects will never be collected by GC as there will always be strong reference to each of the objects. My bet is that current JVM implementations detects such circular references and deals with them fine, but still I would avoid that. That made me to make a small test case for that and see what will happen :)

Comment: Sounds like a bad design.

Comment: Post your real classes. Only with this description is impossible to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insteed of putting reference to `A` in the `C` class, get the `A` from `B` from `C` context, so you will be able to do something like that `c.getB().getA()` or simply `getParent()`

Equality will be measured then if C==C and C.getB()==C.getB() and C.getA()==C.getA() where C.get()->c.getB().getA()

Answer (score 0):

Class C should not contain Class A.  You can see how this would create an infinite circle. A>B>C>A>B>C>A.  Not knowing the exact problem, I would suggest possibly having an Enumeration in C to indicate what "box" it is in, but without directly referencing the box.